# How to use docker secrets in docker-compose and python app?

Tags: python, docker-compose, docker-secrets

I'm trying to use `docker secret` to store username and password. I did the following:

**Step 1: Initiate docker swarm**

`docker swarm init`

**Step 2: Create docker secrets**

`echo "username" | docker secret create app_username -`

`echo "password" | docker secret create app_password -`

**Step 3: Update the docker-compose**

```
version: "3.8"

secrets:
  app_username:
    external: true
  app_password:
    external: true

services:
  backend:
    container_name: lxd-backend
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: backend.dockerfile
    image: lce-backend:latest
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports: 
      - 8085:80
    secrets:
      - app_username
      - app_password
    environment:
      - SERVER_NAME=localhost
      - SERVER_HOST=https://localhost
      - APP_USER_FILE=/run/secrets/app_username
      - APP_PW_FILE=/run/secrets/app_password
```

Then in my python script,

```
print("file: ", os.listdir('/run/secrets/'),flush=True)
```

I get `cannot access /run/secrets: no such file or directory` error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Docker secrets are a swarm feature, I believe.

Comment: I'm new to docker, so I can't really say much about that. I followed the article https://earthly.dev/blog/docker-secrets/ to build my docker-compose.

Comment: *"Docker Swarm is a container orchestration tool that allows the management of containers across multiple host machines. It works by clustering a group of machines together; once they are in the group, you can run Docker commands as you normally would.

To use secrets on your Docker container and through Docker Compose, _you will need to make sure that you are running your Docker Engine in Swarm mode_."*

Comment: So, I suggest that you probably are not running your docker engine in swarm mode

Comment: @SiHa I did the `docker info`, it shows `swarm active`. Isn't that why we did `docker swarm init` in step 1?

Comment: I understand now. I have to deploy the stack and then use it that way. I found more information at https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/stack-deploy/.